How do I validate on change but only after submitting in this React Hook Form?
Right now, I'm using isSubmitted to control whether shouldValidate should be activated in onChange. I want that validation to happen only after the form has been submitted. After that, the validation should happen on each change.
// JS:

const {
  setValue,
  getValues,
  formState: { isSubmitted },
} = useForm<FormData>({
  resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  defaultValues: {
    customFields: []
  },
});

// JSX:

<CustomFields
  fields={getValues('customFields')}
  keysOnly
  onChange={(fields) => {
    setValue('customFields', fields, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldValidate: isSubmitted,
    });
  }}/>

Does React Hook Form have an option that does this automatically? I don't want to rely on isSubmitted.

is this what you are looking for https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode onSubmit

You can add trigger and mode: onSubmit for this.


const {
      setValue,
      getValues,
      formState: { isValid },
      trigger, // Added trigger for manual validation control
    } = useForm<FormData>({
      resolver: zodResolver(schema),
      mode: 'onSubmit', // Validation happens only on submit initially
      defaultValues: {
        customFields: [],
      },
    });
and put this inside your CustomFields component.
    <CustomFields
  fields={getValues('customFields')}
  keysOnly
  onChange={(fields) => {
setValue('customFields', fields, {
  shouldDirty: true,
});

// Manually trigger validation after the form is valid/submitted
if (isValid) {
  trigger('customFields');  // Trigger validation on each change after the first submission
}
  }}
/>



